# Drupal string overrides and HTML

Tags: string, drupal, overriding

I am attempting to override an erroneous error message output by the persistent_login module thus:

```
$conf['locale_custom_strings_en'] = array(
   '<p><b>SECURITY ALERT!</b></p><p>You previously logged in to this site and checked the <em>Remember me</em> box.  At that time, this site stored a "login cookie" on your web browser that it uses to identify you each time you return....'
);
```

I know overrides are working as I can target other strings but this one refuses to be overriden. Not sure why - something to do with the HTML? The persistent_login module is passing this string through `t()` so it should be available to be overridden.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

i dont think you can override error messages. However if this is a production site, it would be best to just disable error messages. You as the developer can view errors from watchdog.

Comment: Thanks - it's not a standard error message, it calls drupal_set_message. In the end I just overrode hook_status_messages. Thanks though.